# Pillow is not installed after removing .temp-builds

Tags: django, docker, python-imaging-library, alpine-linux

**The error**

```
ERRORS:
app_1  | core.Page.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
```

It seems that Pillow is detected as not installed in my docker container if I delete the .temp-builds after installing requirements.txt. I say this because if I remove the '*apk del .tmp-deps*' the error went away. However, I want to remove the .tmp-builds because I learn it's best practice to make the docker container as lean as possible.

**Dockerfile**

```
RUN python -m venv /py && \
/py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client && \
apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-deps \
build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev linux-headers \
python3-dev zlib-dev jpeg-dev gcc musl-dev && \
/py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
apk del .tmp-deps
```

**requirements.txt**

```
django>=3.2.3,<3.3
psycopg2>=2.8.6,<2.9
uWSGI>=2.0.19.1,<2.1
djangorestframework >=3.12.4, <3.20.0
Pillow >= 8.4.0, <8.5.0
```

Any pointer would be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. After looking at the dockerfile, I saw that postgresql-client is not inth e --virtual .tmp-deps. Which means, some dependencies have to stay in the container for some package to work (it was not obvious to me).

What I learn from here is that I need to include jpeg-dev to the line outise the .tmp-deps.

**Updated Dockerfile**

```
RUN python -m venv /py && \
/py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client jpeg-dev && \
apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-deps \
    build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev linux-headers python3-dev  gcc zlib-dev  && \
/py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
apk del .tmp-deps && \
```